# What is the difference between using eval(*code*) and just *code*?

Tags: python

What is the difference between:

```
cerebro.addsizer(bt.sizers.FixedSize, **eval('dict(' + args.sizer + ')'))
```

and:

```
cerebro.addsizer(bt.sizers.FixedSize, dict(args.sizer))?
```

I ran the first one and it worked but the second one causes an error.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: did you try `**dict(args.sizer)`? other than `eval` the `**` is the part that changes the way your program runs

Comment: It's because second one is not the equivalent of the first one (you left of the `**`).

Comment: `eval('dict(' + args.sizer + ')')` is not, in general, going to be equivalent to `dict(args.sizer))`...

Answer (score -1):

Python’s eval() allows you to evaluate arbitrary Python expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based input. This function can be handy when you’re trying to dynamically evaluate Python expressions from any input that comes as a string or a compiled code object.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question (or to anything else).